# Signed Magnitude Representation

Tags: lc3, data-representation

Hi I had a Quick Question,

What does 81 represent in sign and magnitude based on 8 bits?

a. 129 b. -128 c. -127 d. -1 e. none of the above

My Logic is that it would be none of the above as 81 is a positive integer the signed magnitude representation would just be a bunch of 0's in front of it as the value is not negative, would I be correct in this assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes none of the above is the answer.

In signed magnitude the most significant bit is used to represent the sign.  The rest of the bits are used to represent the magnitude of the number. Here since 81 is positive the sign bit is 0.  The magnitude bits are 1010001

81 is 01010001 when represented in 8 bits signed magnitude.